# How to login third-party resources in pop up, receive parameter after login and close pop up after login and receiving parameter

Tags: javascript, servlets, popup

I have such issue. I'm new in javascript. I have to login in third party resource. After login this resource retrieve parameter in redirect url. I need to get this parameter and pass it to servlet. I can open login window in pop up, but how should I get parameter from redirect url from it, pass it to servlet, update parent page and close pop up when I'm logged. My code:

```
var signinWin;
var w = 780;
var h = 410;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popupButton').click(function() {
         signinWin = popupwindow([my url],
                 "SignIn",960,630);
        signinWin.focus();
        var code =  getQueryVariable("code");
        console.log(code);  
        if(code != null){
            signinWin.close();
        }
        return false;
        signinWin.opener.location.reload(true);

    });
});

function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
      var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
      var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
      return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    } 

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = signinWin.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
    }
```

But it doesn't work corectly. Reload of parent page also doesn't work. Please help

Comment: But are third part using form-based authentication? I think you are overcomplicating the scenario. 
Usually in those scenarios you call the authentication giving in the query string a successful login callback URL which the login mechanism would redirect when the user is successfully logged

Comment: @borjagómez no, third party is using oAuth for authentication, so after passing to special url on their website it asks to login and then retrieve parameter. But I can open that login window in new pop up window